# NativeScript Android SDK Installation Error, "Warning: Could not create settings java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Tags: android, sdk, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I have been trying to fix this error that occurs when following [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-linux#system-requirements) guide while running this (sudo $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository") command.

The error:

> Warning: Could not create settings java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)

This is my bashrc screenshot.[image: ]![1]]
While running `tns doctor`:[image: ]![2]]

Comment: I think there is no `/` (slash) between your SDK path and tools

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling and googling a bit, I found out that I had to go back to my base shell by hitting the `exec bash` command and only then it read the $ANDROID_HOME variable. If you're using ZSH add the config to .zshrc file as well.

Comment: I've been helped by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61157708/2313004